# jQuery accordion does not work after its contents are emptied and recreated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-accordion

You will see that on clicking divA , divAA will slide down. on clicking divB, divBB will slide down.

After clearing the main DIV and appending the same contents again, the accordion stops working as shown in this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/p7vUk/2/

Can somebody please explain why it stops working and how to fix it?

Comment: Thanks for showing me this... but what's the question?

Comment: You are aware that jQuery is a Library that is written in JavaScript. Its not like they are two entirely different things..

Comment: @roine - "Jquery fails to work." is most definitely not a question.

Comment: Not only is "Jquery fails to work" not a question, it's not even true: in this case jQuery is doing exactly what it's told... In any case I've edited the question to include an actual question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is the fact removing the original DOM objects that the accordion functionality attached itself to. Just because you add new ones doesn't mean its the same thing. They are entirely new elements, and because of that you have to run the accordion functionality on them again.. Thats about as dumbed down as I can make it sound.

So try this..

```
function clearAndAdd() {

            $("#content").empty();
            $("#content").append('<div id="a">DIV ID A</div><div id="aa">DIV ID AA</div><div id="b">DIV ID B</div><div id="bb">DIV ID BB</div>');
            $("#content").accordion();
        }
```

if that last new line doesn't work try this instead

```
$("#content").accordion('destroy').accordion();
```

Comment: Thank you! `$("#content").accordion('destroy').accordion();` worked

Comment: This will not use the initial properties set by you like `{active: -1, collapsible: true, autoHeight: false, clearStyle: true }`, you need to set these properties again.

Answer (score 4):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/p7vUk/19/).

You need to reset the accordion widget before clearing it. Just calling `.accordion()` will not work since `accordion` is already initialized for the `#content` element so you need to remove the existing accordion widget from `#content` using the `.accordion('destroy')` method.

```
function createAccordion(){
    $("#content").accordion({
        active: -1,
        collapsible: true,
        autoHeight: false,
        clearStyle: true
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
            createAccordion();                
        });


function clearAndAdd() {
    $("#content").accordion( "destroy" ).empty();
    $("#content").append('<div id="a">DIV ID A</div><div id="aa">DIV ID AA</div><div id="b">DIV ID B</div><div id="bb">DIV ID BB</div>');
    createAccordion();                
}
```

Here the creation of accordion is abstracted as a separate method since it has to used twice.